# Link does not establish on one interface

Tags: linux, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

I'm using an old computer as home server/firewall using a linux based distribution (Mandriva). Initially, it had two NICs, `eth0` being the motherboard adapter while `eth1` is a 10/100 PCI network card.
`eth0` was connected to the internal switch to which other devices are connected and `eth1` was connected to the Internet set-top box router.

As time went by and new usages arose, I added two gigabit PCI network cards (DLink DGE-528T) which thus became `eth2` and `eth3`, used for the same functionality as the card they replace. That is, `eth2` is connected to the internal switch and `eth3` is connected to the router.

All was working fine until a few weeks ago when I noticed that I had lost connectivity on `eth3` and looking at the card itself, the cable would no longer 'click' when put into the plug. As it turns out, there were some abuse on the cables which bent the RJ45 connector and made it unreliable.

So, I decided to replace `eth3` with a new gigabit card (TP-LINK TG-3269) that does not seem to have such a fragile connector. This card is thus called `eth4` and `eth3` has been removed from the server altogether.

However, I can't seem to get that new card to work with the router, the leds at the back never turn on when plugged to it. And sure enough, `ifplugd` and `ethtool` both indicate that no link is established. As a a temporary workaround, I'm back using `eth1` so that the server still continues to serve its purpose, albeit in downgraded mode.

I thought that the card was "toast", but I tried a few things and had some strange results, summed up here:

- Connect `eth4` to the internal switch: leds are on, connection established at 1000Mb
- Connect `eth4` to `eth0`: leds are on, connection established at 100Mb
- Connect `eth2` to the router: leds are on, connection established at 1000Mb

So it seems the router does not want to talk to my `eth4` card for a reason that I can't explain.

Looking around at various threads somewhat similar to my issue, I discovered the `mii-diag` tool and ran it without a cable first then with the router cable plugged. Here are the results:

```
[obones@server ~]$ sudo mii-diag eth4
Basic registers of MII PHY #32:  1000 7949 001c c913 0de1 0000 0004 2001.
 Basic mode control register 0x1000: Auto-negotiation enabled.
 Basic mode status register 0x7949 ... 7949.
   Link status: not established.
   End of basic transceiver information.

[obones@server ~]$ sudo mii-diag eth4
Basic registers of MII PHY #32:  1000 7949 001c c913 0de1 c5e1 000f 2001.
 The autonegotiated capability is 01e0.
The autonegotiated media type is 100baseTx-FD.
 Basic mode control register 0x1000: Auto-negotiation enabled.
 Basic mode status register 0x7949 ... 7949.
   Link status: not established.
 Your link partner advertised c5e1: Flow-control 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx 10baseT-FD 10baseT, w/ 802.3X flow control.
   End of basic transceiver information.
```

I know that `mii-diag` is not gigabit aware, but what I find interesting is that in the second case, it detects that there is a link partner, and yet, the link is not established.

What could be the reason for this? What should I try next?

---

As required, here are a few additional details.

The router definitely is gigabit capable and it was working fine at that speed with `eth3` before the connector failed. When connected to `eth2`, it worked as well at gigabit speed.

`dmesg -T | grep eth4` does not output anything

Here is the output from lspci:

```
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet [10ec:8169] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet [10ec:8169]
00:0b.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: D-Link System Inc DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter [1186:4300] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: D-Link System Inc DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter [1186:4300]
00:0d.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82557/8/9/0/1 Ethernet Pro 100 [8086:1229] (rev 08)
00:13.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
```

And the one from lshw:

```
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: a
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
       logical name: eth4
       version: 10
       serial: 14:cc:20:05:38:22
       size: 10MB/s
       capacity: 1GB/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=64 link=no maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10MB/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:a000(size=256) memory:f7109000-f71090ff memory:c0180000-c019ffff(prefetchable)
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: D-Link System Inc
       physical id: b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
       logical name: eth2
       version: 10
       serial: 1c:7e:e5:26:54:a0
       size: 1GB/s
       capacity: 1GB/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.10.10.254 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=1GB/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:a400(size=256) memory:f710b000-f710b0ff memory:c01a0000-c01bffff(prefetchable)
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82557/8/9/0/1 Ethernet Pro 100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: d
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 08
       serial: 00:90:27:ca:ba:e8
       size: 100MB/s
       capacity: 100MB/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e100 driverversion=3.5.24-k2-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.253 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=56 mingnt=8 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100MB/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:f710a000-f710afff ioport:ac00(size=64) memory:f7000000-f70fffff memory:c0000000-c00fffff(prefetchable)
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 13
       bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:14:85:c0:ea:2b
       size: 10MB/s
       capacity: 100MB/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=half ip=10.10.10.250 latency=64 link=no maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10MB/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f710d000-f710d0ff
```

Do you think that forcing the `eth4` card at gigabit without autonegocation solve this? If I'm correct, the command would be this:

```
ethtool -s eth4 duplex full speed 1000 autoneg off
```

I'll try tonight, but why doesn't it work to begin with?

Comment: Is the router switch definitely gigabit? I read you've tried another gigabit card and it connects at gigabit, did Internet work? We have a gigabit network and with cards configured to "auto-negotiate" we have unreliable connectivity. Setting a speed/duplex fixes this... Don't know why...

Comment: Is there any output from `dmesg -T | grep eth4`? Also, can you please post the output of `lspci -vnn | grep -i net`  and of `lshw -C network`?

Comment: I have edited the original post with the requested information, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You do not seem to have the firmware for the driver. Depending on your distro, it should be in a package called `firmware-linux`, `firmware-linux-nonfree`, `linux-firmware`,or some such thing. Your command is fine, but pls read here too, http://serverfault.com/questions/106160/should-network-hardware-be-set-to-autonegotiate-speeds-or-fixed-speeds

Comment: Well, for `dmesg`, there was no output because it is full with firewall messages about packets being dropped according to some reject rules. I thus suspect it's not very relevant, I'll try to reboot the server later on and run the command immediately.

As to forcing the speed, thanks for the link, it does feel wrong to have to do it as well.

Comment: No, wait, firewall rejecting packets??? That **may** very well be relevant, why are you so sure it isn't?

Comment: Because they are on `eth1` and I had them on `eth3` before the connector broke. I configured shorewall to log them, and it's at the IP level, much higher than the physical level.
It's just that these messages clutter up the dmesg output very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I now know why `eth4` won't establish link and it came to me after fiddling with the cables a bit more. What should be known is that even if it's at home, I'm using a patch bay to dispatch the various connections. This means the server is connecting to the router via this kind of arrangement:

```
server <--> cable <--> plug <--> wall <--> plug <--> patch bay <--> plug <--> router
```

In my initial message, I said that `eth2` would connect to the router at 1G and that was correct at the time.

But I tried again this week and it did not happen anymore, which immediately made me realize that the original issues I had with `eth3` were after some cable abuse.
And sure enough, using another plug on the wall to connect to the patch bay allowed `eth4` to properly connect at 1G to the router.

So, in the end, it is hardware related, just not the kind of hardware I was expecting it to be.

Many thanks to all who commented on my issue, I learned quite a few tricks with you guys and sorry for wasting your time when I should have more thoroughly check the cables.